# Ubuntu cannot pair with bluetooth keyboard

Tags: 15.10, bluetooth

Ubuntu 15.10 cannot pair with bluetooth keyboard.

In the GUI, it says "setting up '....keyboard' failed.

If using the bluetoothctl, the error message shows 'Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationCanceled'

```
[NEW] Controller 00:1A:7D:DA:71:13 odin-desktop [default]
[NEW] Device 00:18:00:3B:C1:B2 FILCO Bluetooth Keyboard
[bluetooth]# pair 00:18:00:3B:C1:B2 
Attempting to pair with 00:18:00:3B:C1:B2
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.InProgress
[CHG] Device 00:18:00:3B:C1:B2 Connected: no
[bluetooth]# pair 00:18:00:3B:C1:B2 
Attempting to pair with 00:18:00:3B:C1:B2
[CHG] Device 00:18:00:3B:C1:B2 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 00:18:00:3B:C1:B2 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 00:18:00:3B:C1:B2 Connected: yes
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationCanceled
[CHG] Device 00:18:00:3B:C1:B2 Connected: no
```

I tried according to https://communities.intel.com/thread/62848?start=0&tstart=0

and https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=197469&p=2

Those do not help.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, some time in 2008, `bluez` had a major overhaul, but the development team forgot to create any documentation on how to use the new version.

According to [this site](http://www.bennybottema.com/2010/08/08/how-ubuntus-broken-bluetooth-support-came-to-be/), where you can find many more details on what happened and why,

> The developers of bluez, once the nice Bluetooth package everyone could live with, decided it was time for a major overhaul: they merged the packages bluez-libs and bluez-utils and then some. And with ‘and then some’ meaning completely changing the way Bluetooth devices are configured and thereby breaking backwards compatibility.

An update on this article confirms that the same problem exists in 2016. No one knows how to use the new `bluez`.

However, there are a few workarounds. The author of that article has created a workaround that may or may not work for you, especially since it is for Ubuntu 9.04. You can try your luck though, here: http://www.bennybottema.com/2010/01/28/how-to-connect-a-bluetooth-keyboard-in-ubuntu-9-04-jaunty-and-9-10-karmic-workaround/

Unfortunately, it seems like there is no known fix for this. No one can seem to find anything out about `bluez`. From what I've researched on this, there is still no documentation available, nor any answers to the keyboard pairing problem, which seems to be fairly common. I think your best best it to try the workaround I linked and see if it works.